# Blazor Server App: How to design so that the client requests receive the same data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

Let's suppose we have this simple classical timer in default Blazor Server.

```
<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        Console.WriteLine($"Count incremented: {currentCount}");
    }

    private Timer timer;

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimerInterval;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            // Start the timer
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }

    private void OnTimerInterval(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        IncrementCount();
        InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // During prerender, this component is rendered without calling OnAfterRender and then immediately disposed
        // this mean timer will be null so we have to check for null or use the Null-conditional operator ?
        timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Right now when I open this page in the browser time starts from zero for every new window(as expected). However, I want to open multiple pages in the browser and every page should see the same time (if the time shows 10 in my first window and I open a new window I want the time in both to be the same). How can I achieve that?

In general, I want to create a simple SPA that shows the real-time stock price values to the users.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SignalR would probably be the preferred Microsoft solution for this problem, since it provides [real-time web functionality to apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

At a high level, you would need to:

1. Create a [`Hub`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-5.0) on the server that would be responsible for handling the connection with clients and broadcasting messages (in your case stock information).
2. Assuming you already have some sort of service for polling/receiving stock updates, that service could use the [`IHubContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to publish updates to the clients through the `Hub`.
3. The client would need a [`HubConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-razor-component-code-for-chat) to receive messages from the server.

Here's a full example of a Chat app using a similar approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app

---

Since I couldn't find a good example of an application using these components similar to your use case: I put together a simple repo that can be found here: https://github.com/t-j-c/Stack.Blazor.SignalR

Comment: I am getting very close to this. Regarding your second point, can I randomly generate some data (for the price, volume) and push it to the client using IHubContext?

Comment: Sure, as long as wherever you're generating that data has an instance of `IHubContext` it could do `_hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync(someStockData)`

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions will save me a lot of time. Can you share some simple examples of Hub that resembles my use case (I am new to this stuff and easily lose direction when I search for information)

Comment: @Gray_Rhino I couldn't find a simple example so I put one together myself :) Edited the answer to include a link

Comment: this is awesome. I tried to implement my work based on your example but something is missing. I created a new question and would appreciate it if you could have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Just make currentCount static.

```
private static int currentCount = 0;
```

It should work.